Instagram Marketing API: Show Ad to a specific User
For my Use case, im planning a Live demo where i start an Instagram Marketing Campaign. After launching the Ads, the goal is to present an Instagram Account where the Advertisement can be seen. So it really only needs to be visible on that specific account.
Whats the best way to do this?

I saw that there is a sandbox mode, but it states that it doesnt actually launch ads. is that correct?
Are the are other test environments i could use?
If it has to be the real instagram, is it even possible to narrow the targeting down to a point it could be a guaranteed to show up on that account?

